# npm mssql package intellisense not working when im offline?

Tags: npm, visual-studio-code

I'm currently working on a nodejs project in an offline domain and came across this issue that I cant seem to find anything about.

Apparently even after installing the mssql package in visual studio code, intellisense only works when i have network.

if that helps, I installed the package from an online computer and then moved it to the offline computer, but the same problem shows even if i just unplug my computer and reopen vscode.

its also worth mentioning that packages like express and morgan does have intellisense even when offline.
Is there an option to also save the package's intellisense locally?
thanks!

mssql package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql

Answer (score 0):

So as it turns out, and even though I checked multiple times if it's network related or not, the problem were with some settings that I set up 2 years ago when I were coding with powershell.

Removing it worked, so always take a look at the vscode settings (suggestions/intellisense categories)